# How to run program with n-command in C?

Tags: c, operating-system, signals, fork, parent-child

I have now compile it one by one. I also facing a problem about terminating the processes.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int n = 1;
int f = 1;

signal(SIG_ERR, sig_hand1);
signal(SIGINT, sig_hand1);

for (f; f < argc; f++){ \\create n-numberd fork.
    nfork(f, argv);
}

for (n; n<argc; n++){ \\terminate the child one by one.
    Rturn(n, argv);
}
return 0;
```

}

With the Rturn function

```
void Rturn(int n, char *argv[]){

int status;
struct rusage usage;
struct timeval start;
struct timeval end;
wait4(-1, &status, 0, &usage);
if(WIFSIGNALED(status)==1){
        char *str = strdup(signame[WTERMSIG(status)]);
        printf("\nThe command %c%s%c is interrupted by the %s\n\n", '"', argv[n], '"',str);
    }
    else if(WEXITSTATUS(status) == 255)
        printf("The program experienced an error in starting the command: %s\n\n", argv[n]);
    else
        printf("\nThe command %c%s%c terminated with returned status code = %d\n\n", '"', argv[n], '"', WEXITSTATUS(status));

}
```

And nfork

```
void nfork(int n, char *argv[]){
if(fork() == 0){
    printf("Process with id:%d created for the command: %s\n", getpid(), argv[n]);
    fflush(stdout);
    if(execlp(argv[n], argv[n], NULL) == -1){
        printf("\nexeclp:  %s\n\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

}

I found that the message is not returned by the process but by the n in the loop.

For example, if I run

```
./test cd fake //with command cd and "fake"
```

Then it will return

```
monitor experienced an error in starting the command: cd
```

The expected return should be like this

```
monitor experienced an error in starting the command: fake
```

How can I locate the correct child to the variable n?

Comment: Please ask about only one question/issue per post. You can always make multiple posts for each seperate issue. Keeping it to a single question will keep it focused and more answerable.

Comment: I am sorry about that, I will edit it asap. @kaylum

Comment: If you want to wait for a specific process then you need to tell `wait4()` which one.  The PID will have been returned by `fork()` (supposing that that's what the mysterious `nfork()` uses to create child processes).  We haven't enough information to suggest how best to convey that from `nfork()` to `Rturn()`.

Comment: Since the program require to handle n commend with n processes using pipe, so I used the nfork function to create child processes with execlp inside. I will edit it. @JohnBollinger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On success, the `fork()` function returns twice.  In the parent process, its return value is the process ID of the new child.  In the child process, the return value is 0.  It is by the process ID returned to it that the parent can recognize specific children so as to wait for them, send signals to them, *etc*..

Your `nfork()` function presently ignores the return value of `fork()` except to check whether it is zero.  This is wrong for two reasons:

1. The parent does not distinguish between success and failure of the `fork()` call.  It just assumes that it succeeds.
2. The parent wants to be able to later associate specific children with the corresponding value of *n*.  Individual processes are identified by their process IDs. Only in `nfork()` is there an opportunity to associate child process IDs with *n* values, but the function fails to take advantage of it.

There are any number of ways that the association between child indices and child process IDs could be recorded, but the simplest would probably be to create an array to store them in.  `nfork()` would need to fill the array, and `RTurn()` would need to draw from it the PID to wait for, which it would then supply to `wait4()` as its first argument.

Comment: Does it means I need to include one more variable pid in both `RTurn()` and `nfork()`?
I do it but my array returned a wrong value..

Comment: @happyhappy, I cannot evaluate code that you have not presented, and in any case, the above is already a complete answer to the question posed.  I will add, however, that if you want to follow my suggestion to use an array, then it matters where that array is declared.  It cannot be local to `nfork()` or `RTurn()`, both because they don't know how large to make it, and because then it would not have a sufficient lifetime.